# How to get partial results from Google App Engine's urlfetch?

Tags: google-app-engine, streaming, urlfetch

When I'm using `google.appengine.api.urlfetch.fetch` (or the asynchronous variant with `make_rpc`) to fetch a URL that steadily streams data, after a while I will get a `google.appengine.api.urlfetch_errors.DeadlineExceededError` as expected. Since it is a stream that I want to sample, setting the `deadline` to a higher value can't ever help, unless the stream finishes (which I do not expect to happen).

It seems there is no possibility of getting the partially downloaded result. At least the API doesn't offer anything. Is it possible to

- either request the downloaded part
- or only ask for a certain amount of data (since I can estimate the stream's rate) to be downloaded?

[**Clarification**: Since it is a stream, requests with a `Range` header will be answered with `200 OK` and not `206 Partial Content`.]

Answer (score 4):

In your call to `urlfetch.fetch`, you can set HTTP headers.  The `Range` header is how you specify a partial-download request in HTTP:

```
resp = urlfetch.fetch(
    url=whatever,
    headers={'Range': 'bytes=100-199'})
```

if those are the 100 bytes you want.  The HTTP status code you get should be 206 for such a partial download, etc (none of that's GAE-specific).  See e.g http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving for details.